# Finding largest sub-matrix on basis of frequency

Tags: matrices

I have a matrix $A[N][M]$ with characters in it. I want to find out the largest sub-matrix such that the frequency of all characters in it are even and at most one character occurs odd number of times.

Eg - 
$$ A= 
        \begin{matrix}
        b & c & a & d & c \\
        a & b & c & d & e \\
        a & f & h & f & a \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

$a:4,b:2,c:3,d:2;e:1,f:2,h:1$

I have to decrease no of odd frequency characters or make their frequency even.

I thought about calculating prefix sum of frequency of each character for every cell. And then eliminate that row or column which makes frequency of a character odd.

So I removed $h$ first and then $e$ so as to make it even i.e $0$ times. Finally I got this :

$$ A= 
        \begin{matrix}
        b & c & a & d  \\
        a & b & c & d \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

But this isn't optimal at all. Is there a systematic and efficient way to do this ?

Comment: What's the context where you encountered this problem?  Can you credit the source of this problem?  It seems remarkable that the exact same question has been asked on [CS.SE], on the same day: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/76819/755.  Programming contest?  Shared course?

Comment: @D.W. My friend came up with this question during classes. I don't know the original source though. The other question is similar if we consider digits to be characters though in case of digits, it can be solved faster.